# java integer array resets to default values after pushing the values using foreach

Tags: java, arrays

Looks strange why the integer array resets again to the default values.

```
int[] y = new int[5];
int z = 0;

for(int j : y) {
    j = z++;
    System.out.print(j); //0 1 2 3 4
}

for(int j : y) {
    System.out.print(j); //0 0 0 0 0
}
```

Comment: Your integer array is blank..So when you it will print 0 because its integer

Comment: Your first loop is not actually writing to the array because j is a copy of the current array value, not a reference to it.  You just need to make j a reference in the first loop: for (int & j : y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is pass by value. Therefore when you change the local variable `j` that contains the value of an array element, the element is not changed, only the local variable.

To change the array element, you need to do:

```
for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    y[j] = z++;
    System.out.print(y[j]); // 0 1 2 3 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*j* will have the *value* of y[k] inside the loop, but writing to it will not write through to the array.

Use a normal for loop if you want to modify the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = z++;
    System.out.print(y[i]); //0 1 2 3 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value to j, which contains copied value from array, not the reference.

What you need is :

```
for (int i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = z++;
    System.out.println(y[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the values to the integer array you are assigning it to a temporary variable j .Try the below it will print the updated values

```
int[] y = new int[5];
int z = 0;

for(int j =0 ;j< y.length ;j++) {
    y[j] = z++;
    System.out.print(y[j]); //0 1 2 3 4
}

for(int j : y) {
    System.out.print(j); //0 1 2 3 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `for` loop, the value in the variable `j` that you are printing is not a value that is coming from the array, because you assigned a new value (from `z`)before printing it (`j`)...